# /storage/emulated/0/AndroidAPP/addon_data/plugin.audio.mp3streams/artist_icons/David Bowie.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Tags: android, eclipse, extract, unzip

I want to extract zip files in android. It is working fine for other Zip fILES, But i have one zip files which can not extract to any path of sdcard.
It gives me this error.

```
  /storage/emulated/0/AndroidTVAPP/addon_data/plugin.audio.mp3streams/artist_icons/David Bowie.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

**Unzip File JAVA CLASS**

```
public class UnzipUtility  
{ 
/**
 * Size of the buffer to read/write data
 */
private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;
/**
 * Extracts a zip file specified by the zipFilePath to a directory specified by
 * destDirectory (will be created if does not exists)
 * @param zipFilePath
 * @param destDirectory
 * @throws IOException
 */
public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException 
{
    File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
    if (!destDir.exists()) 
    {
        destDir.mkdir();
    }
    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
    ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    // iterates over entries in the zip file
    while (entry != null) 
    {



        String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();

        String filePath2 = File.separator + entry.getName();// filePath;

        if (null != filePath2 && filePath2.length() > 0 )
        {
            int endIndex = filePath2.lastIndexOf("/");
            if (endIndex != -1)  
            {
                filePath2 = filePath2.substring(0, endIndex); // not forgot to put check if(endIndex != -1)

                 Log.e("File path=",""+filePath2);

                 File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
                 File dir = new File(root.getAbsolutePath() + "/AndroidTVAPP"+File.separator+filePath2);
                  if(dir.exists() == false){
                      dir.mkdirs();  
                  }



            }
        }  


        if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
            // if the entry is a file, extracts it
            extractFile(zipIn, filePath);
        } else {
            // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
            File dir = new File(filePath);
            dir.mkdir();
        }
        zipIn.closeEntry();
        entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
    }
    zipIn.close();
}
/**
 * Extracts a zip entry (file entry)
 * @param zipIn
 * @param filePath
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath) throws IOException 
{
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));
    byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int read = 0;
    while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
        bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
    }
    bos.close();
}
```

}

Comment: Must be the space in the filename. Did you try encoding it?

Comment: @KNeerajLal May be there would be space, becasue that zip files is about 45 mb and have many files, should i upload the unzip class here, so that you could see it and culd help me

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an escape character to specific that there is a blank in the file name.

Try this,

```
String path = "/storage/emulated/0/AndroidTVAPP/addon_data/plugin.audio.mp3streams/artist_icons/";
String fullPath= path + "David Bowie.jpg";
fullPath = fullPath.replace(" ", "\\ ");
```

Or you can use `Uri.parse(path)`.

```
public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
    ...
    ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(Uri.parse(zipFilePath)));
    ...
}
```

Comment: First you [need to create the directory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/dirs.html). And then you need to [move the files](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/move.html).

Comment: I have fixed the code, while i put some line which create directory the above code has been updated and it is working fine, Any wasy thanks for telling me that we should create directory before to move files